# How to get the color of a checkbox checkmark?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```html
<!--Lightning Component: -->
<div class="slds-m-around--small">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="stagename"><h1 style="font-size:16px"><b><u></u></b></h1></label>
    <lightning:input class="selected slds-checkbox_faux" type="checkbox" value="No Stock" label="Exclude out of stock" aura:id="getvalue" onchange="{!c.checkbox}" />
    <!--<ui:inputSelect aura:id="stagename" class="slds-select" label="" change="{!c.onStockChange}"/>-->
</div>
```

```css
/* Style.css: */ 
.THIS .selected .slds-checkbox_faux:after{
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(212, 61, 110) !important;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(212, 61, 110) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct general selector for checkbox checkmark of `<lightning:input type="checkbox"/>` (where you can redefine its color) is:

```css
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + .slds-checkbox_faux::after, 
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + .slds-checkbox--faux::after, 
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .slds-checkbox_faux::after, 
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .slds-checkbox--faux::after, 
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + .slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox_faux::after, 
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + .slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux::after {
    /* display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 0.25rem;
    width: 0.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) rotate(-45deg); */
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(212, 61, 110) !important;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(212, 61, 110) !important;
}
```

So in your case, you don't have to explicitly specify `slds-checkbox_faux` for `class` attribute because after render it would be applied for the very top `<lightning-input>` HTML element.